# Transport Layer Security without Server Certificate

Tags: ssl

Is there a way to secure the transport layer without any server certificate?

I read RFC 4492 and it is saying there is a key exchange algorithm name ECDH_ANON which does this, but on many of the links I found that it is not recommended to use this as it is prone to MITM (Man in the Middle) attack.

I just want to mention that my server is not public and my server and clients are in the same local subnet. My server is accepting connection on websocket.

What are the options if I want to secure my transport layer? I don't want to do it by manually encrypting the payload.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a solution called [TLS-SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-SRP), if supported by your server and client(s).  But probably more common is to just install a self-signed server certificate for your local system, or set up your own CA and issue your own cert to the server and install the CA's root cert as a trusted root on your clients.

Comment: Thanks razor. TLS-SRP is new to me. I will explore this. I can not use self signed certificate for this as my clients are iOS and Android app and adding my CA in mobile is not easy and also not recommended.